# run occ as your http user | Owncloud 9 on Debian Jessie

Tags: debian, owncloud

I'm stuck while installing owncloud 9 on my debian jessie server.

**Running `occ` as user `www-data`**

The manual asks me [here](https://doc.owncloud.org/server/9.0/admin_manual/configuration_server/occ_command.html#http-user-label) to run the `occ` command as my http-user, which is `www-data` under debian.
Trying to run `sudo -u www-data php occ` (first without any options) I get  the following problems:

- `sudo`isn't avaible as root.
- as a non-root user, I get `-su: 5: sudo: not found`
- `su - www-data` gives me `This account is currently not avaible.` due to `www-data`'s `/nologin` option.

Is anyone able to tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

do it with the www-data user. occ is mainly the terminal version of the administration web app with some small additions. To keep things safe occ shouldn´t be able to do anything else Apache (or Nginx) can to to the (file) system. It also keeps you from changing any permissions wrecking your Owncloud installation.

Greetings,

Mike

Comment: Thanks so far @Mike !
The only question is: how do I use `www-data` ? It is set as no-login...

Comment: It's written in the manual you linked just as well…

> sudo -u www-data php occ

Comment: @Blizzz I updated the question with all error messages that I'm getting. Sorry if I didn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 2):

As it seems, `sudo` was simply not installed. I thought this package was self-evident to be installed on a new debian system, but as it seems this isn't the case.

`apt-get install sudo` solves the problems mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

**Some deductions on the matter:**

I understand that Ubuntu is based on unstable Debian, so stable Debian is better for production.

'sudo' for production provides possible safety holes.
Also add, that the fewer packages on your server less likely to have security holes.

Debian understands it like this and me too.

**About the question:**

1. su -s /bin/sh www-data
2. php occ files:scan your_nextcould_user

**My result:**

Starting scan for user 1 out of 1 (jonas)
**Home storage for user jonas not writable**
Make sure you're running the scan command only as the user the web server runs as

+---------+-------+--------------+
| Folders | Files | Elapsed time |
+---------+-------+--------------+
| 0       | 0     | 00:00:00     |
+---------+-------+--------------+

I'll see why... :)